# html5 canvas scroll

Tags: html, canvas

i have a requirement that I need to create a canvas and draw inside it programattically and put it inside a marquee, all these through javascript. Is it possible ? a few pointers please

As a follow-up: i wrote the following, it creates the canvas but does not scrolll it, but the hard coded marquee works !

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>
<marquee>you are welcome</marquee>

<input type="button" value="click" name="btn" onClick="btnClicked();"/>



<script>
function btnClicked()
{
alert('here');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');      
// Draw whatever on your canvas  
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(70, 140);
context.lineTo(140, 70);
context.stroke();
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(canvas);
var marquee = document.createElement('marquee');  
marquee.appendChild(div);  
document.body.appendChild(marquee);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It only works if you wrap all that in a `blink` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, though probably ugly.

I'll take your question literally...

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Draw whatever on your canvas

var marquee = document.createElement('marquee');

marquee.appendChild(canvas);

document.body.appendChild(marquee);
```

Comment: looks fine, thanks, but assuming that my page is loaded, when i do this on a button click, will it appear immidiately in the page, as in vb applications ? secondly, can i delete / remove this canvas after the scroll is over ?

Comment: @sunu Sorry, I couldn't understand what you meant. If it is a new question, ask a new question and someone else may be able to assist you :)